# derivative of t distribution cdf wrt degrees of freedom

Tags: calculus, derivatives, probability-distributions, power-series, partial-derivative

Given the cdf of a t distribution as follows:

$T_\nu(x)=\frac{1}{2} + x\Gamma(\frac{\nu+1}{2}) + \frac{_2F_1 (\frac{1}{2},\frac{\nu+1}{2};\frac{3}{2};-\frac{x^2}{\nu})}{(\pi\nu)^{1/2}\Gamma(\frac{\nu}{2})} $,

where $_2F_1$ is the hypergeometric function. We want to compute the derivative

$\frac{\partial T_\nu(x)}{\partial\nu}$.

Thanks!